# Uploading a Python package into PyPI

Tags: python, pip, pypi, twine

I am following the instructions in the PyPI link below to upload my Python package into PyPI:
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

but I am stuck at the step where I need to run twine after installing it, which is the step below:

Once installed, run Twine to upload all of the archives under dist:

```
python3 -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

When I ran the above command in the command prompt (I am using cmd in Windows), I get the following message:

```
'twine' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to change directory after installing twine from the directory where I pip installed twine to the directory where my dist/* folder is sitting? Or I somehow did not install twine properly? (I did get some warning messages when I installed twine but it did say twine was successfully installed at the end - I have attached an image of the warning messages here).

[image: twine_issues]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the issue is the warnings: `twine` is not being installed where Python can find it. Omitting the `--user` flag will likely fix this, or editing the `PATH` as it suggests.

Comment: Thanks, I have now done this by editing the `PATH` and have installed twine without errors. I am now getting another error in the next step when I run `python3 -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*`. The error I am getting is 'InvalidDistribution: Cannot find file <or expand pattern>: 'dist/*''. I have followed the [guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and there is a dist folder that I have created in the prior steps.

Comment: The guide has a space between `...legacy/` and `dist/*`. Is there meant to be a space here?

Comment: Ok, I managed to resolve my issues. Couldn't find `dist/*` because I needed to change directories. And yes, there needs to be a space between `...legacy/` and `dist/*`